# Sorted lists and Parallel Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I'm refactoring code that was written some time ago when linq and delegates didn't exist and a lot of the code is embarrassingly parallelizable so I'm using `AsParallel` whenever I can but I'm not quite sure what happens when ordered lists are involved in such queries. For example,

```
/* suppose we have the following list
SortedList<DateTime, SomeClass> list1
*/

var projection = list1.AsParallel().Select(t => t.Key);
var skippedProjection = list1.AsParallel().Select(t => t.Key).Skip(1);
var zipped = projection.AsParallel().Zip(skippedProjection, someComputation);
```

My question is the following: Is the ordering preserved in parallel queries? In other words will the above example work as I expect or will the `Select` queries following `AsParallel` return things in random order depending on what strategy is used behind the scenes?

Comment: Using `AsParallel()` whenever you can actually make your performance worse, even on multi-core processors.

Comment: @svick: I don't pepper it willy-nilly but in certain obvious places where there are very few data dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, using `AsParallel()` will cause the results to be unordered.  That being said, you can explicitly specify that you require ordering by adding a call to [AsOrdered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642142.aspx).  For example:

```
var zipped = projection.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Zip(skippedProjection, someComputation);
```

Some operations handle ordering automatically, so this is not always required - but enforcing order will slow down the operation and/or reduce the amount of parallelism, so it's typically not the default.

For details, I recommend reading [Order Preservation in PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677.aspx).  That article discusses the details of what preserves order and what does not.